# Python3: Как из функции вывести список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Я новичок и только разбираюсь, не могу сообразить как сделать вывод списка из функции.
Есть большой вывод json, в котором есть список:

```
dataorg = {'ДопВидДеят': [
    {'Код': '10.11', 'Текст': 'Переработка и консервирование мяса', 'Дата': '2017-06-29'},
    {'Код': '10.12', 'Текст': 'Производство и консервирование мяса птицы', 'Дата': '2017-06-29'},
    {'Код': '10.13.3', 'Текст': 'Производство мясных (мясосодержащих) консервов', 'Дата': '2017-06-29'}
]}
```

Мне нужно сделать функцию, вывод из которой будет:

- Переработка и консервирование мяса;
- Производство и консервирование мяса птицы;
- Производство мясных (мясосодержащих) консервов;

Пробовал так:

```
def okve():
    for i in range (0, len(dataorg)):
        ok = '- ' + dataorg['ДопВидДеят'][i]['Текст'] + ';'
        return(ok)
print(okve())
```

Но мне возвращается только:

- Переработка и консервирование мяса;

При этом вывод из функции мне нужен для использования в другой функции.  Подскажите, какие есть варианты решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` возвращает только то что в него передали, и завершает работу функции.

Нужно либо аккумулировать список внутри функции и вернуть полный список в конце:

```
def okve():
    ok = []
    for i in range (0, len(dataorg['ДопВидДеят'])):
        ok.append('- ' + dataorg['ДопВидДеят'][i]['Текст'] + ';')

    return ok

print(okve())
```

Либо возвращать значения последовательно с помощью `yield`, превратив тем самым функцию в генератор (но чтобы получить список, нужно будет обернуть вызов функции в `list`):

```
def okve():
    for i in range (0, len(dataorg['ДопВидДеят'])):
        ok = '- ' + dataorg['ДопВидДеят'][i]['Текст'] + ';'
        yield ok

print(list(okve()))
```

Если нужно вывести не в виде списка (в квадратных скобках), а каждый элемент с новой строки, то можно объединить результат в цельную строку с помощью `join`:

```
print('\n'.join(okve()))
```

Или так:

```
print(*okve(), sep='\n')
```

---

Вообще, если вам нужно перебрать элементы списка, то `range` не нужно:

```
def okve():
    ok = []
    for item in dataorg['ДопВидДеят']:
        ok.append('- ' + item['Текст'] + ';')

    return ok
```

```
def okve():
    for item in dataorg['ДопВидДеят']:
        ok = '- ' + item['Текст'] + ';'
        yield ok
```

Comment: А что лучше? Превращать функцию в генератор или как у вас в первом способе?

Comment: @Евгений, если потом превращать в список, то без разницы. Если не превращать, а просто как-то обрабатывать каждое значение, то при большом количестве элементов будет экономия памяти. В принципе, можно сделать генератор, который генерирует бесконечную последовательность (например, последовательность чисел Фибоначчи). Превратить такую последовательность в список невозможно, но можно например получать элементы последовательно, пока выполняется какое-то условие.

Comment: В первом варианте python ругается на то что  name 'ok' is not defined. Во втором варианте выдаёт только "Переработка и консервирование мяса;" во всех трёх print

Comment: @АртёмЛебедев поправил

Comment: @АртёмЛебедев, 2 - потому что длину не от всего словаря нужно брать, а только от значения по ключу `'ДопВидДеят'`. Поправил.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помог вариант № 2 с yield и '\n'.join(okve())

Comment: @АртёмЛебедев, хорошо. Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым (поставить галку слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
dataorg = {
    'ДопВидДеят': [
        {
            'Код': '10.11', 
            'Текст': 'Переработка и консервирование мяса', 
            'Дата': '2017-06-29'
        }, 
        { 
            'Код': '10.12', 
            'Текст': 'Производство и консервирование мяса птицы', 
            'Дата': '2017-06-29'
        }, 
        {
            'Код': '10.13.3', 
            'Текст': 'Производство мясных (мясосодержащих) консервов', 
            'Дата': '2017-06-29'
        }
    ]
}

def okve():
    for i in dataorg['ДопВидДеят']:
        print(f" - {i['Текст']}")
        
okve()
```

---

**Update**

```
dataorg = {
    'ДопВидДеят': [
        {
            'Код': '10.11', 
            'Текст': 'Переработка и консервирование мяса', 
            'Дата': '2017-06-29'
        }, 
        { 
            'Код': '10.12', 
            'Текст': 'Производство и консервирование мяса птицы', 
            'Дата': '2017-06-29'
        }, 
        {
            'Код': '10.13.3', 
            'Текст': 'Производство мясных (мясосодержащих) консервов', 
            'Дата': '2017-06-29'
        }
    ],
    'ДопВидДеят222': [
        {
            'Код': '10.11', 
            'Текст': '222 Переработка и консервирование мяса', 
            'Дата': '2017-06-29'
        }, 
        { 
            'Код': '10.12', 
            'Текст': '222 Производство и консервирование мяса птицы', 
            'Дата': '2017-06-29'
        }, 
        {
            'Код': '10.13.3', 
            'Текст': '222 Производство мясных (мясосодержащих) консервов', 
            'Дата': '2017-06-29'
        }
    ]
}

        
def okve():        
    for i in dataorg:
        for j in dataorg[i]:
            print(f" - {j['Текст']}")
        print()
        
okve()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Тут я понял что нужно быть конкретнее. Мне нужен вывод функции, чтобы потом использовать эти данные в другой функции. Поэтому тут print мне не подойдёт.

Comment: @АртёмЛебедев см. мой ответ.

Comment: @АртёмЛебедев я обновил ответ посмотрите