# Как сделать вывод списка из функции в docx через docxtpl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

В продолжение [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1142431/python3-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA).

Есть словарь:

```
dataorg = {'ДопВидДеят': [
    {'Код': '10.11', 'Текст': 'Переработка и консервирование мяса', 'Дата': '2017-06-29'},
    {'Код': '10.12', 'Текст': 'Производство и консервирование мяса птицы', 'Дата': '2017-06-29'},
    {'Код': '10.13.3', 'Текст': 'Производство мясных (мясосодержащих) консервов', 'Дата': '2017-06-29'}
]}
```

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
file1 = DocxTemplate("file1.docx")
def okve():
    for i in range (0, len(dataorg['ДопВидДеят'])):
        ok = '- ' + dataorg['ДопВидДеят'][i]['Текст'] + ';'
        yield ok
    
con1 = {
        'okved' : "\n".join(okve());
       }
file1.render(con1)
file1.save('file.docx')
```

в file1.docx поставлен тег `{{ okved }}`

Вывод в Python через `print` показывает всё отлично:

```
 - Переработка и консервирование мяса; 
 - Производство и консервирование мяса птицы;
 - Производство мясных (мясосодержащих) консервов;
```

А вот вывод в файле docx даёт список без переводов на новую строку:

```
- Переработка и консервирование мяса; - Производство и консервирование мяса птицы; - Производство мясных (мясосодержащих) консервов;
```

Экспериментировал в подстановку строки `"\n".join(okve());` вместо `"\n"` различные варианты:
`\r`, символы юникода, скрытые символы Word, функцию `RichText()` из docxtpl, не помогло.

Ищу дополнительные варианты решения вопроса.

---

PS Метка docxtpl не ставится.

Comment: 1) У вас же словарь, а не список. 2) Попробуйте "\r\n".

Comment: 1. Ок 2. Пробовал, результат тот же, только пробел добавился.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> The `RichText()` or `R()` offers **newline**, new paragraph, and page
> break features : just use `\n`, `\a`, or `\f` in the text, they will
> be converted accordingly.
>
> ...
>
> `context = { 'var':R('my text') }` and `{{r <var> }}` in the template
> (note the `r`)

Т.е. в `file1.docx` должно быть `{{r okved }}` и в коде:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate, R

con1 = {'okved' : R("\n".join(okve()))}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, надо мне лучше читать документацию, я пропустил этот момент.